# MySQL Trigger not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

TL;DR: Query works from MySQL CLI but NOT from PHP, as if the triggers were not fired by PHP.

I have a mySQL structure which looks like this:

- `entity` is the "parent" table with `id` as PK
- `contact` is a "child" table with `entity_id` as PK and FK on `entity`
- `person` is a "grand-child" table with `entity_id` as PK and FK on `contact`

I have created some triggers so that when I insert a new row in `contact`, it first inserts a new row in `entity` and uses the new `id` as `entity_id`. Idem for `person` and `contact`. Triggers are all made on the same model, here's one:

```
DELIMITER #
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS contact_insert_trig;
CREATE TRIGGER contact_insert_trig BEFORE INSERT ON `contact`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO entity (cat_id) values (1);
    SET NEW.entity_id = (SELECT id FROM entity ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
    SET NEW.entity_cat_id = 1;
END; #
```

So, for instance, when I insert a new row in `person`, the first trigger creates a row in `contact` which, via the second trigger, creates a row in `entity`, all with matching `id`s.

This WORKS in MySQL but NOT in PHP. The same query:

```
INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name) VALUES ("Bob", "McIntosh")
```

works in the mySQL CLI (all rows are created and match up) but fails when called with `mysqli->query()` in PHP7 with the error:

```
Field 'entity_id' doesn't have a default value
```

How can I make it work in PHP as well? Or do I have to go through the process of creating all parent tables manually?

Comment: Hm... this really shouldn't be a php issue. The mechanism that detects a row insert is not dependent on where the query came from. This isn't an answer at all, but whether you write the code that creates the parent entries in MySQL or in php you're still doing it "manually", and I lean toward keeping my logic all in one place. Triggers are easy to lose track of. So while I honestly have no idea why you are seeing this behavior, I'd advocate using php rather than triggers on philosophical grounds.

Comment: Agree on both accounts. Shouldn't matter where the query comes from, so I must be missing something. As for the logic being all in one place, I'd decided early on that the DB should be robust on its own. The php is only an interface, but some people still can (and will have to) access the data directly from mySQL. I don't want them to be able to mess anything up by creating / updating / deleting rows. Hence the triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, now queries work from PHP as well :

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

(or don't turn on `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`).